# Console.Clear() after a timeout

Tags: c#, ascii, countdown, timespan

I'm developing a game in C# console for homework.  I made a kind of introduction to the beginning of the game in ASCII art.  What I want is to show this piece of code for 5 seconds and then go to the game.

I searched for information and tried with `Console.Clear()` but does not accept `TimeSpan` parameter.

I'm not asking you to do my work, but I seek guidance to do this.

I leave the code of ASCII art, wallpaper is taken from CM Punk "Best in the World".

```
class Programa
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // BEST IN THE WORLD!!!!
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("       Z");
        Console.WriteLine("         Z=");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.Write("++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write("MZZ.");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.Write("++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write("$ZZ:.");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.Write("++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write(".ZZZZ:.");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.Write("++++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write(".ZZZZZ:.");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.Write("++++++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write(".ZZZZZZZ:.");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.Write("++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write(".ZZZZZZZZZ:.");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.Write("++++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write(".zZZZZZZZZZZZ:.");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("                zZZZZZZZZ:.");
        Console.WriteLine("                    zZZZZZ$ZZ:..:7ZZZZZ7$.                                     ");
        Console.WriteLine("                        zZZZZZ. .7.  .$$ZZz                                    ");
        Console.WriteLine("                           zZZZ+:  :Z     ZZ$                                  ");
        Console.WriteLine("     *            *          zZZZZz   Z  Z$Z$             *             *      ");
        Console.WriteLine("*    *    *  *    *    *    zZZZZZZZ   Z$   ZZ       *    *    *   *    *    * ");
        Console.WriteLine("  *******      *******      ZZZ:ZZ.:Z:  Z  Zz          *******       *******   ");
        Console.WriteLine("   *****        ****        ZZ+ZZZZ.  Z7Z$ZZZ:          *****         *****    ");
        Console.WriteLine("  *******      *******      $ZZZI     $Z$$$ZZZZ,       *******       *******   ");
        Console.WriteLine("*    *    *  *    *    *     ZZZZZZ   Z$   ZZ  ZZZZ:.*    *    *   *    *    * ");
        Console.WriteLine("     *            *            zIO,,     :7Z$   7ZZZZ=,   *             *      ");
        Console.WriteLine("                                   $       ZZO    7ZZZZ$+7                     ");
        Console.WriteLine("                                  OZO$.....Z~...7ZZZZI:ZZZZZ+$                 ");
        Console.WriteLine("                                    ZZO:...$ZI.,    7ZZZZ,Z                  ");
        Console.WriteLine("                                   .Z$.OI:?ZOZ,      $77ZZ                     ");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.Write("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write(".ZZZZZZZ:.");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++");
        Console.Write("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write(".C7ZZI.");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++");
        Console.Write("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write("7ZZ:.");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++");
        Console.Write("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write(".Z.");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("                              BEST IN THE WORLD");


    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a timeout, but more a delay, right? Timeouts are usually when something is requested or some action is being performed but it doesn't complete in the given time frame.

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

will pause your app for 5 seconds.

Comment: Enjoy, others also suggested the same answer.
I wrote `app` but with programs with several threads (yours have one),  it stops the current thread.

Answer (score 2):

Some options are [`Thread.Sleep(5000)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) or [`Task.Delay(5000)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873.aspx). In a console app, it usually won't matter which of the two you use. In most other circumstances, if you're on .NET 4.5 or higher, I'd recommend the latter, since the new .Net async functionality is much better.

Comment: There's not really much of a reason to use asynchrony in a console app, at least most of the time.  It just doesn't have an inherently asynchronous model, unlike most other UI frameworks.

Comment: Hm, true, I'll change my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could just let the current thread sleep for 5 seconds:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Thread.Sleep` to pause execution of the current thread for a period of time.